# Get parameters with value

Tags: haskell

I would like to get the value of parameters from the input.
I have a program that read input, and I want to be able to get value like: `./test --params value` and in my program get the `value` as an INT.

```hs
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    print args
```

Without using getOpt() 
Thanks

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [`optparse-applicative`](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative) package, which does pretty much exactly what you need. But `getOpt` seems pretty useful as well; why can’t you use it?

Comment: @bradrn I think it's better to do that myself, actually getArgs return me a Data.Array. I think the best way to do that is iterate through this array. But how can I make a simple for loop on this Data.Array ? Like this code:

for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
   printf("%s\n", argv[i]);

Comment: @AlexisR Haskell doesn’t have for loops — or any kind of loop, in fact, although you can simulate them if you really have to. And `getArgs` doesn’t return a `Data.Array` — it returns a list, which is a completely different (and much simpler) data structure.

Comment: If you want to implement this yourself, you’ll probably want to recurse through the list you get from `getArgs` until you find the `"--params"` item, then return the next item from the list of arguments.

Comment: @bradrn Yes, this is what I would like. Can you give me an example of how to iterate through the list and how to get the next element inside the iteration ?

Comment: That would be a function with multiple lines, so hard to fit in a comment. But I’ll try to make it as a paste or gist or something and link to it.

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/xfpi8Mjr — I’ve annotated each line of code, in case I’ve used any syntax you haven’t learnt yet

Comment: @bradrn Thanks you. How can I pass as argument to the function getParam the `args` ? https://www.codepile.net/pile/qrzoO4Wz and in this paste this return me an error no `Nothing` (parse error on input), this is my first experience on Haskell :)

Comment: You need to define `getParam` as a separate function — I’ll edit your pile to show you.

Comment: If this is your first experience with Haskell, I highly recommend finding a good book to learn from. I found http://learnyouahaskell.com/ to be very good (although I’ve heard that some people have found it hard to follow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the following function:

```hs
getParam :: [String] -> Maybe String
getParam [] = Nothing
getParam ("--param":next:_) = Just next
getParam (_:xs) = getParam xs
```

And you can use it as follows:

```hs
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let param = getParam args
    print param
```

If you’re interested in the details, `getParam` works by recursion:

- The first line is a type signature stating that `getParam` takes a list of strings as its only argument, and it returns either a string or nothing (that’s what `Maybe String` means).
- The second line states that if there are no arguments, it returns nothing.
- The third line states that if the first argument is `--param`, match the next argument (by assigning it to the identifier `next`) and return it (albeit wrapped in `Just`; look up the ‘`Maybe` data type’ if you want to know more).
- The fourth line states that if neither of the previous cases have matched, discard the first item in the list and try again.

There is one slight problem with this implementation of `getParam`: it returns a `String`, but you want an `Int`. You can fix this by using the `read` function, which can be used to convert a `String` to many other types, including `Int`. You could insert `read` in two places in the program: you could either replace `Just next` by `Just (read next)` (to get `getParam` to return an `Int`), or you could replace `getParam args` by `read (getParam args)` (to get `getParam` to return an `String`, and then convert that to an `Int` outside `getParam`).

Comment: Thanks you. Do you know how can I change the `getParam` function to returning an Integer instead of Maybe String ? I think it's Maybe Integer but it return me an error. And an other question, it is possible to return a value (according to the type of the function) instead of "Nothing" ?

Comment: @AlexisR For your first question: I did actually write instructions (in the last paragraph) on how to change `getParam` to get it to return an integer. What error are you getting? And for your second question: `Maybe` is a data type which is _defined_ as being either `Nothing` or `Just _someValue`, so if you don’t want to use `Nothing`, you’ll have to change the type of `getParam`.

Answer (score 5):

> Without using getOpt() Thanks

Huh. You're bound to reimplement at least *parts* of it, probably badly, but sure, let's assume your code is actually so special that it needs a hand-written arg parsing code.

Since `getArgs :: IO [String]`, we already have the input tokenized by spaces, which is neat. However, in your case you want *specifically* `--params value`, and obtain `value` by `Int`.

There are numerous problems to solve here:

- there might not be `--params` in the list at all
- or there might be multiple instances of it
- it might have no following token
- or the following token might be another `--otherparam`
- or the following token might not parse as `Int`

All of the above (and more) are possible to happen, because the input is completely unsanitized.

Solving all of the cases brings us back to using `getOpt`, so let's assume that there's exactly one `--params` in the list, and that it's followed by something that parses as an `Int`.

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main = do
   args <- getArgs
   let intArg = (read :: String -> Int) . head . tail . dropWhile (/= "--params") $ args
   print intArg
```

If any of those assumptions is broken, this code will fail in numerous ways. Each of the problems requires a careful decision about a failure path. You might want to abort execution, provide a default value, you might want to use exceptions or a `Maybe` access API. Ultimately, you'll figure out that this is a solved problem and simply use `getOpt`:

```
import System.Console.GetOpt
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

data Arg = Params Int deriving Show

params :: String -> Arg
params = Params . read

options :: [OptDescr Arg]
options = [ Option ['p'] ["params"] (ReqArg params "VALUE") "Pass your params"]

main = do
    argv <- getArgs
    case getOpt Permute options argv of
        (o,_no,[]) -> print o
        (_,_,errs) -> ioError (userError (concat errs ++ usageInfo header options))
    where header = "Usage:"
```